# Selecting first row per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with three columns: `A,B,C`.

The values are:

```
+---+-----+----+
| A |  B  | C  |
+---+-----+----+
| 1 | -10 |  5 |
| 1 |   0 |  5 |
| 1 |  10 |  5 |
| 2 |  10 | 12 |
| 2 |   0 | 12 |
| 3 | -10 | 14 |
| 4 |   0 |  8 |
| 4 |  10 |  8 |
| 5 |   0 |  6 |
| 5 |   1 |  6 |
| 5 |  -5 |  6 |
+---+-----+----+
```

If I first order the data by column `A`, then column `B`, then column `C` (although I did make all column `C` values the same per column `A` value) how would I select the "first row" per column `A`?

So, this should result in:

```
+---+-----+----+
| A |  B  | C  |
+---+-----+----+
| 1 | -10 |  5 |
| 2 |   0 | 12 |
| 3 | -10 | 14 |
| 4 |   0 |  8 |
| 5 |  -5 |  6 |
+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: the last one should be {5,-5,6}

Comment: There is also a detailed answer at dba.stackexchange.com: [Retrieving n rows per group](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/57105) with comparison of different approaches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT  a, b, c
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b, c) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER BY
        a
```

or

```
SELECT  mi.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT  a
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.a = md.a
        ORDER BY
                b, c
        ) mi
ORDER BY
        a
```

Create a composite index on `(a, b, c)` for the queries to work faster.

Which one is more efficient depends on your data distribution.

If you have few distinct values of `a` but lots of records within each `a`, the second query would be better.

You could improve it even more by creating an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_mytable_da
WITH   SCHEMABINDING
AS
       SELECT  a, COUNT_BIG(*) cnt
       FROM    dbo.mytable
       GROUP BY
               a

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
       pk_vmytableda_a
ON     v_mytable_da (a)

GO

SELECT  mi.*
FROM    v_mytable_da md
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.a = md.a
        ORDER BY
                b, c
        ) mi
ORDER BY
        a
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! Love your first answer

Comment: Got a slight problem, I am using this for code which is a function, returning a table... but it wont let me include the ORDER BY statement .... EDIT: It's ok I have used a procedure

Comment: @Porcupine: `ORDER BY` has no sense inside a function. You should append `ORDER BY` at the end of the query using the function: `SELECT  * FROM myfunction(2) ORDER BY a`. Optimizer will push it into the query if it proves efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dealld
                             ORDER BY Price, Dealld) rn
   FROM DealOffers) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.