# Selecting columns from a stored Proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc and I am trying to select all rows from it.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SEL_My_Func 'arg1','arg2','ar3'
```

didnt work. So I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM EXEC dbo.SEL_My_Func 'arg1','arg2','ar3'
```

but this also didnt work. How do I get to test my stored proc returns correct results?

I have had to use a proc, rather than a function because I have an ORDER BY as part of the SQL, see: [Selecting first row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930347/selecting-first-row-per-group)

Lastly, am I right in thinking there is no problem limiting which columns are returned from the stored probc, you just cant specify which rows (otherwise you would be better using a SQL function)?

Comment: You can't compose the output of a stored proc within another statement - you can't restrict which columns and rows are produced - short of dumping the entire output in a temp table, and then `SELECT`ing from there - but then you need to apply the `ORDER BY` to that `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXEC dbo.SEL_My_Func 'arg1','arg2','ar3'
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I cannot only pick a subset of the proc columns to return?

Comment: See Romil's solution for that or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3):

The solution you are using qwill not work:

workarounds are there

```
SELECT a.[1], a.[2]
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','myserver';'sa';'mysapass',
    'exec mydatabase.dbo.sp_onetwothree') AS a
```

or split your task in two queries

```
Declare @tablevar table(col1,..
insert into @tablevar(col1,..) exec MyStoredProc 'param1', 'param2'

SELECT col1, col2 FROM @tablevar
```

Comment: However, the OP's whole reason for placing their code within a stored proc was so that they could specify an `ORDER BY`. The second definitely isn't guaranteed to respect the order of rows returned by the stored proc in the final output. I don't think the first one is either.

Comment: @Damien, the order by wasn't in the normal sense. The stored proc returns an un-orded set of results. However, these results had already been ordered by on a column which was grouped by (probably best you see the link i included at the top)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, OP can use the order by clause with the approaches I have shown in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about functions is incorrect.  You can use partition functions to select the first row in group.

Here is an example to find the first dealer_id for each client:

```
select client, dealer_id
from (
     select client, dealer_guid
         , RANK() over ( partition by client order by dealer_id) as rnk
     from Dealers
) cd where rnk = 1
```

This can also be done with a function call as well as with a table (my example).