# How to retrieve the following data from MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

**UPDATED**

I have the following data in my database, I would like to retrieve data in highlight red border (to get the latest maintenance data of each equipment).

Data:

[image: SQL Data Picture]
(I have updated the picture)

How should I construct the query?

Comment: I guess you don't want something like....select * from table where convert(varchar, maintance_time, 112) = '23122019' *

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting first row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930347/selecting-first-row-per-group)

Comment: @Nissus, I want to get latest maintenance date time data only... for all equipment

Comment: When you ask 'for each equipment' you mean group by name ?group by type ? or both?

Comment: So, did you try anything beforehand? Seems a bit odd... however, you could perform a subquery such as `SELECT Name, Type, MAX(MaintenanceTime) AS MaxTime FROM ... GROUP BY Name, Type` and perform a join to your initial table such as `... JOIN ... on a.Name = b.name and a.Type = b.Type and a.MaintenanceTime = b.MaxTime`

Comment: @Nissus by name only....

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like that?

```
   select name, max(maintenance_time) 
    from table 
    group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Answer:**

This query below should work. Do update table name before running the query.

```
SELECT [Equipment], [Type], MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [MaintenanceTime], 131)) AS [Most_Recent_Maintenance]
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY [Equipment], [Type]
```

The additional bit of code I added was around datetime conversion of your `MaintenanceTime` column. SQL only does `MIN/MAX` filtering commands accurately when it's the right data type.

Based on what I see in your table, there's a potential it may not be (See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). I added an additional query to the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b2fbbbb9d8960b2affd8428ccca97850) for you to see the conversion.

---

**Old Answer:**

Based on the picture provided, it seems like each set of maintenance data is posted in 'batches'. Assuming the batch data is all posted using the same date/time, you can use the following query to obtain all records on the latest posting date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [INSERT_TABLE_NAME]
WHERE DAY([Maintenance Time]) = (SELECT DAY(MAX([Maintenance Time])) FROM [INSERT_TABLE_NAME])
```

Or if your equipment is not always maintained together in the same batch timings, here's a query to figure out the most recent time each piece of equipment was maintained:

```
SELECT [Name], [Type], MAX([Maintenance Time]) AS [Most_Recent_Maintenance]
FROM [INSERT_TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY [Name], [Type]
```

Be sure to update `[INSERT_TABLE_NAME]` to reflect your table naming. I've also created a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3290e4962d99457907a02452ee41709e) for you to view what the query (with your dataset) will look like.

Comment: Hi MTay, I have updated my data, hope you understand... actually the maintenance will not the same for each equipment..

What I need to query is the latest maintenance data of each equipment sset

Comment: Hey there, I've updated my answer to reflect the new data / requirement. Let me know if you encounter any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all your desired data arrives at the same time:

```
select *
from T
where maintenance_time = (select max(maintenance_time) from T);
```