# Select the record based on a condition when the first 2 columns match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as shown below

| emp_id | emp_name | flag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Y | 1 |
| 1 | A | N | 5 |
| 1 | B | N | 5 |
| 1 | C | N | 8 |
| 2 | X | N | 1 |
| 2 | X | Y | 5 |
| 2 | Y | N | 5 |
| 2 | Z | N | 2 |

I need to pick the rows when the first two columns are the same(duplicates), then you pick flag 'Y'. The output should look like

| emp_id | emp_name | flag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Y | 1 |
| 1 | B | N | 5 |
| 1 | C | N | 8 |
| 2 | X | Y | 5 |
| 2 | Y | N | 5 |
| 2 | Z | N | 2 |

Tried a sql inner join but gives only records with 'Y' flag

Comment: Please tag correctly.  SQL Server or Postgres?  They're not the same.  Also, please do not use images for sample data or code.  Post them in text format so that it can be easily used.  And show your code.  That way we can help you figure out why you only get records with a 'Y' flag.

Comment: Also, please provide the data as formatted text.  Not images.  Say that, *for some bizarre reason*, we wanted to test our answer after we had written it, we'd need the data to test against.  I for one, however, am not going to copy-type that data, when you could have just copy-pasted the text...

Comment: What happens when multiple rows exists for a given <emp_id, emp_name> where flag is Y? Do you assume this is not possible? Seems you have a "first in group" situation generally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting first row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930347/selecting-first-row-per-group)

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have fixed the question! Thanks for the answers too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the rows you want, as in:

```
select emp_id, emp_name, flag, count
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by emp_id, emp_name
      order by case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Awesome. Did a union between two flags and it was time-consuming. This is GREAT!