# Take only first row from sets of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like below. Normally it has more columns, but for simplicity I attached most important here. Rows with the same `ItemId` are almost the same. Sometimes `ts` is different for flag equals to `0` or `1`. Not always there are two rows for one `ItemId`, but they are always ordered like below (`flag asc`). I want to always fetch only 1 row, but if there are both flags, I want to take with `Flag=0`.

FROM:

| ItemId | Flag | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 0 | 2021-01-01 02:00 |
| x | 1 | 2021-01-01 03:00 |
| y | 0 | 2021-01-01 03:00 |
| y | 1 | 2021-01-01 02:00 |
| z | 1 | 2021-01-01 01:00 |
| w | 1 | 2021-01-01 01:00 |

TO:

```
ItemId|ts
------|-----------------
x     |2021-01-01 02:00
y     |2021-01-01 03:00
z     |2021-01-01 01:00
w     |2021-01-01 01:00
```

I tried with `MAX`, but it can not be used cause there is no logic for ts, so dates would be wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting first row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930347/selecting-first-row-per-group)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select *
from(select t.*, row_number() over(partition by itemid order by flag) as seq
     from table t
    ) t
where seq = 1;
```